# How to highlight a region on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, maps

How can I highlight/cover a region or multiple regions with different colors (for example 3 US states), using google maps polygon arrays?
I found a tuto on google code about how to draw a polygon but it's not giving detailed information.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi were you able to highlight states? I am looking for the same thing but can't find any solution. Regards

Answer (score 12):

This documentation on Google is about as straight forward as you can get.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html

View the source of this page.  Copy and paste the code into your own page and start from there.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple.html

In the example above you simply need to make more than one instance of bermudaTriangle and name it something else and add it to the map.