# How can I highlight an area in the Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I want to highlight an area someone's searching for on Google Maps.

For example, something like what [this place displays](https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/Viman+Nagar,+Pune,+Maharashtra/@18.5686731,73.9098571,15z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x3bc2c146e61484b5:0xb6482cf7a8b4b3b0):

[image: an area on a map named Viman Nagar, with a strong red outline and highlighted inside to distinguish it from the surroundings]

How can I do this using map api v3?

Comment: I've clarified the title here and made the question a bit better arranged, and included a screenshot of what you might be looking for. Could you edit it to clarify whether you know about the area in advance - i.e. you know the exact points you want to draw those lines along - or do you just want to be able to tell the API "please highlight Viman Nagar"?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the question. I want to tell the api to highlight Viman Nagar if that is possible. But I think in current API version it is not possible. So I atleast want to know where I can find the co-ordinates for drawing any region.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible through the current maps API/places API, unless you actually have these points yourself (from your question, it doesn't seem like it). Google's APIs will only return you a bounds, not a set of coordinates (or even encoded polyline) to be able to draw an outline around a specific area.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431855/how-to-highlight-a-region-on-google-maps) might be usefull!

But again, you'd need to have the points from what I saw.